# How to use lists in recursive functions Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I'm writing a function that recursively traverses the file system, and returns a list of all files with the `.txt` extension.

The `pass_test_func` parameter is just a function that can be run and checked (i.e. is the file greater than 100 bytes, etc) - The `nothing` function (set as its default), simply returns its argument.

My implementation:

```
def visit(dname, pass_test_func=nothing):           
    directory = os.listdir(dname)                   
    byte_list = []
    for file in directory:
        file_dir = os.path.join(dname, file)
        if os.path.isfile(file_dir) and file_dir.lower().endswith('.txt'):
            size = os.path.getsize(file_dir)
            if pass_test_func(size):
                byte_list.append(str(size) + ' ' + file_dir)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_dir):
            visit(file_dir, pass_test_func)
    return byte_list
```

My problem is that when I recursively call `visit` in the following lines

```
elif os.path.isdir(file_dir):
                visit(file_dir, pass_test_func)
```

the `byte_list` is cleared to empty again. I understand why this is happening, but have no idea how I would fix it. The list has to be defined within the definition of `visit`, so whenever I use recursion it will always be reset no matter what right? Maybe some other data structure is better suited, like a tuple or dictionary?

Comment: You should know that someone put effort into a solution to your problem already: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir

Comment: @KlausD.: Or on older Python, you can use [the PyPI `scandir` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir) (which `os.scandir` was based on). On Windows, this will reduce the system call (and associated I/O) overhead from three calls per directory (check if file, check if directory, list directory) + two calls per file (check if file, get size) to just one check per directory; on Linux, it can't avoid the `stat` for the size check, but it's still a reduction to one call per directory plus one per file (the type check is provided free on the `DirEntry` object).

Comment: @KlausD.: Mind you, in most cases, you're probably better off just using `os.walk` (which is `os.scandir` based once `os.scandir` is available), since it handles a lot of stuff for you. The whole function simplifies to `def visit(dname, pass_test_func=nothing): return [os.path.join(root, f) for root, _, files in os.walk(dname) for f in files if pass_test_func(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, f)))]` with `os.walk` (one-lined because this is a comment; you could easily write a proper generator function that doesn't re-`join` the `root` and `f` over and over).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an optional argument that can be used in the recursive case:

```
# Using * makes byte_list keyword-only, so it can't be passed by normal callers by accident
def visit(dname, pass_test_func=nothing, *, byte_list=None):           
    directory = os.listdir(dname)           

    # When not passed explicitly, initialize as empty list
    if byte_list is None:
        byte_list = []
    for file in directory:
        file_dir = os.path.join(dname, file)
        if os.path.isfile(file_dir) and file_dir.lower().endswith('.txt'):
            size = os.path.getsize(file_dir)
            if pass_test_func(size):
                byte_list.append(str(size) + ' ' + file_dir)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_dir):
            # Pass explicitly to recursive call
            visit(file_dir, pass_test_func, byte_list=byte_list)
    return byte_list
```

As an alternative, as [suggested by Blorgbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517099/how-to-use-lists-in-recursive-functions-python/47517153#comment81990314_47517099), since you return `byte_list`, use that for your `visit` calls, changing only a single line in your original code:

```
        visit(file_dir, pass_test_func)
```

to:

```
        byte_list += visit(file_dir, pass_test_func)
```

This creates additional temporary `list`s, but that's usually not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

Your function returns `byte_list`, so just append the returned value when you make your recursive call, instead of throwing it away as you currently do:

```
elif os.path.isdir(file_dir):    
    byte_list += visit(file_dir, pass_test_func)
```